# Identifying if a URL is present in a string

Tags: php, regex

Hi can someone help me identify if a url is present in a string using PHP?

I want to pull in a full string i.e. "Hi please visit http://domain.com/12345 today" and strip out the full url not just the domain name.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this article from Jeff Atwood's blog "Coding Horror": [The Problem With URLs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001181.html)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

[RegEx Guru: Detecting URLs in Text](http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/)

Read up on this and understand the trade-offs of each approach. For me, `\bhttp://\S+` is totally acceptable, because I'm not interested in catering to those who would put links with spaces (or surround their links with parens) into plain text... (but I'm not very accomodating I guess)

Answer (score 1):

here's an example

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://www.sitepoint.com');

preg_match_all('~(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)~', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```