# Find url from string with php

Tags: php

following code is used to find url from a string with php. Here is the code:

```
$string = "Hello http://www.bytes.com world www.yahoo.com";
preg_match('/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/', $string, $text);
$hypertext = "<a href=\"". $text[0] . "\">" . $text[0] . "</a>";
$newString = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/', $hypertext, $string);
echo $newString;
```

Well, it shows a link but if i provide few link it doesn't work and also if i write without http:// then it doesn't show link.  I want whatever link is provided it should be active, Like stackoverflow.com.

Any help please..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Regular Expression to get a URL from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720805/php-regular-expression-to-get-a-url-from-a-string)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A working method for linking with http/https/ftp/ftps/scp/scps:
`$newStr = preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/]+!', "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",$str);`

I strongly advise NOT linking when it only has a dot, because it will consider PHP 5.2, ASP.NET, etc. links, which is hardly acceptable.

**Update:** if you want www. strings as well, take a look at [this](http://www.phpro.org/examples/URL-to-Link.html).

Comment: well @axiomer, but it's not active if i write www.example.com

Comment: Updated my solution with a link (I didn't test it but it should work, I think).

Comment: This doesn't work if the URL has a hyphen (-).  The link ends before the hyphen.

Comment: this worked for me but I noticed that when I linked youtube videos it broke the link at the `=` sign so I modified it to work with youtube video links `$newStr = preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?&_/=]+!', "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",$str);`

Comment: Updated code to make it work when the URL has a hyphen (`-`), `%` or `=` sign: `$newStr = preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?%=\-&_/]+!', "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",$str);`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to detect something like `stackoverflow.com`, then you're going to have to check for all possible TLDs to rule out something like `Web 2.0`, which is quite a [long list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). Still, this is also going to match something as `ASP.NET` etc.

The regex would looks something like this:

```
$hypertext = preg_replace(
    '{\b(?:http://)?(www\.)?([^\s]+)(\.com|\.org|\.net)\b}mi',
    '<a href="http://$1$2$3">$1$2$3</a>',
    $text
);
```

This only matches domains ending in .com, .org and .net... as previously stated, you would have to extend this list to match all TLDs

Comment: This only works for the domain portion.  If the string includes directories and/or files, the link will end before those.

Answer (score 0):

@axiomer your example wasn't work if link will be in format:

`https://stackoverflow.com?val1=bla&val2blablabla%20bla%20bla.bl`

correct solution:

```
preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.?%=&_/]+!', "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $content);
```

produces:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com?val1=bla&val2blablabla%20bla%20bla.bl">https://stackoverflow.com?val1=bla&val2blablabla%20bla%20bla.bl</a>
```

Comment: preg_replace('!(http|ftp|scp)(s)?:\/\/(.*)+!', "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $str);