# Codeigniter: Submit textarea with <script> inside

Tags: php, jquery, regex, codeigniter, code-injection

As I've no idea where to search for this - perhaps somebody here can help me.

I need the user to add something like this in a textarea:

```
<script> var foo  bar; </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://foobar.de/mylist.js"></script>
```

But Codeigniter seems to have an in-built code-injection protection - so all I get after submission is:

```
[removed] var foo  bar; [removed] 
[removed][removed]
```

How could I change this? I know it's insecure, but I need to parse the URL out.

As alternative I need a jQuery function to parse this URL out.... and I'm not very familiar with regEx. ^^

My PHP parser for this looks like this (copied from somewhere ^^):

```
$reg_exUrl = '/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
if (preg_match($reg_exUrl, $_POST['code'], $matches)) {
        $jsUrl = $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: You can try setting `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` to false. This config can be found in application/config/config.php

Comment: Or use `$this->input->post('textareaName', false)` which will disable XSS filtering when fetching the value of that textarea.

Comment: Thx. The solution from Gavin would be nice - so I could use this only in this one case - without unsecure all forms - but unfortunately it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gavin's comment works fine. It may be that you're not seeing it because the script tags will make it invisible (in the event you are trying to `echo` or `print` the result).

```
function index()
{
    echo form_open();
    echo form_textarea('test');
    echo form_submit('', 'Submit');
    echo form_close();

    if($this->input->post())
    {
        echo "<pre>";

        $textified = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $this->input->post('test', false));
        echo "textified string = $textified <br><br>";

        // find URL. Regex from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2721152/183254
        preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', $textified, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

        echo "URL in textified string: " . $result[0][0];
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

It seems that the above is dependent on `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` being set. When `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;`, all fields are filtered no matter what and there is no way to have selective fields not go through the filter. As such, the above won't work if it's set to `TRUE` as it seems to be in your case.

The default for `$this->input->post()` is for XSS filtering to be false, so the `false` in the example above is redundant as well.

It seems the only way to do it is to leave `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` and set `$this->input->post('filtered_item', true);` on all input fields where you **do want** XSS filtering on and use just `$this->input->post('unfiltered_item');` for fields where you need the script tags.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/182774/#871558

Comment: Thx, but this doesn't work for me - I don't know why. I still have all the [removed] in the string - and no <script>.

Comment: Thx. You're right. With the XSS Filter set to false it works - but to change all other inputs is no option. So I've deciced to make a jQuery solution, which parses me the needed url from the string...