# tinymce 5 and n1ed - upon save to db, it also includes text "[removed][removed]"

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I am using tinyMCE 5 and n1ed.  I have no idea where this is coming from and have search google with zero results.  When I submit my textarea to db for saving, it always includes "[removed][removed]".  I remove n1ed and it doesn't happen.  I am stumped how to even debug.  Any guidance very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I failed to mention I was using Codeigniter3.

I turned off xxs_clean in the validation rules and it worked.

Refer to this:  [Codeigniter: Submit textarea with <script> inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364030/codeigniter-submit-textarea-with-script-inside)